# Where is the Westworld park actually located?

Tags: westworld-tv

Where exactly is the park in Westworld located, is it an actual place or a man made ecosphere?

In Episode 4 (The Dissonance Theory), we see the Man In Black using a matchstick to flow up a door but instead the scene is cut to QA where they ask their supervisor for a 'pyrotechnic' effect. Also, later in the scene we see a man's head explode due to the cigar the Man In Black had given him. Which makes me think how such explosions are can take place in the normal world and I am now questioning the nature of reality of their world.

Comment: The cigar was actually a concealed explosive. Obviously they can't have guests or hosts detonating those whenever they like in order to keep the guests safe, so there's a disconnect between the fuse and the actual detonation, which is triggered remotely.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142124/is-westworld-an-isolated-part-of-the-country-or-something-else

Answer (score 6):

The first episode of Season 2 gives a very strong hint.

When the Chief Operating Officer of Delos arrives at Westworld, he has a brief argument with a Chinese soldier, and he says:

> See this?
>
> It's an official statement executed by your country giving Delos, and consequently me, authority over this entire island.

This would imply that Westworld (and the other Delos parks) is located on one of the many islands in the South China sea.

Comment: If anyone can translate what the Chinese soldier says, I'd gladly add it to the quote