# Does Ford have Arnold's access code?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

In S01E10 of Westworld, we learn that Maeve's core programming has been revised by someone with Arnold's access code. Since Arnold is long dead, does it mean that Ford is making changes for his new narrative through Arnold's access code?

Comment: I edited. Is it better now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it mean that Ford is making changes for his new narrative through Arnold's access code?

## Yes

Ford even tells Bernard/Arnold that Arnold didn't know how to give the hosts sentience.

> "I told you, **Arnold didn't know how to save you**,"
>
> "I do. You needed time. Time to understand your enemy. To become stronger than them. And I'm afraid that in order to escape this place you will need to suffer more. And now, it is time to say goodbye old friend. Good luck."

This link at [**Insider.com**](http://www.thisisinsider.com/westworld-finale-twist-ford-2016-12) explains it quite neatly...

> Ford kept the hosts in the park because he believed they needed more time to truly come to understand the nature of their reality. And he wanted them to have 35 years worth of suffering at the hands of humans before he set them free. Ford knew that if the hosts had built up a store of memories — memories of being tormented for human's entertainment — that their final ascension to consciousness would be more devastating and complete.

Ford has access to the whole codebase anyway since he created the Bernard/Arnold "host". **Using Arnold's access code is just adding a layer of mystery (probably for plot reasons)**

As for Maeve, Bernard reveals that her whole narrative, including the escape to the "mainland", was coded into her...so, obviously by Ford.

Her decision to stay in the park and search for her "daughter" is another issue to be explored in later seasons/episodes.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I had a theory that I posted here: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88623/theory-arnold-and-ford-continue-living-through-hosts-programming

Comment: Where does "mainland" refer to?

Comment: That's another question which, I think, has been asked before. We know that Westworld is on an island but we don't know where the island is. - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65582/where-is-the-westworld-park-actually-located and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142124/is-westworld-an-isolated-part-of-the-country-or-something-else

Comment: I couldn't find my answer there. I googled the *meaning* of mainland. In the context of the series, does it refer to outside (of the park) world?

Comment: @Asmani in the series they always refer to "mainland" when speaking of the outside world.

Comment: @Luciano Thanks. I watched the first season a year ago, I had forgotten.