# Are Arnold and Ford living through hosts' code?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

Arnold used his own voice as the inner monologue of the hosts. Several times we see Dolores having conversations with Arnold in her mind. In S01E10 there's a **log-in from Arnold's access code**. These all may suggest that Arnold is living through the hosts' programming. In S01E10 Ford says: "**Mozart, Beethoven,
and Chopin never died. They simply became music**."

And the last piece of evidence: At 01:19:57 Arnold asks Dolores "Whose voice you've been hearing all this time" where **the voice of Arnold, Ford and Dolores merges**. I believe Ford too incorporated his consciousness to the hosts' programming.

Are there other evidence supporting or against this theory?

Comment: Additional evidence: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmdskjf-nqM

Comment: S02E06, seems Ford is living digitally in the Cradle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I believe Ford too incorporated his consciousness to the hosts' programming.

## NO

It's clear that the voices that Delores hears are **programmed** in the attempt by Ford to give the hosts sentience...and eventually Delores' mind starts an internal dialogue.

> The key to Dolores' achieved sentience lies in the Bicameral mind theory — a theory Arnold used to "bootstrap" consciousness. He programmed Dolores and the other hosts to hear "the voice of God" in their head, and **his hope was that their own internal thoughts would eventually take over.**
>
> ..
>
> *Dolores hasn't been guided by the ghost of Arnold or by some of Ford's new narrative code.* **The whole time she was truly hearing her own thoughts, her own voice.** There wasn't a second host version of herself or anything like that, but she was having visions of herself as a manifestation of her developing consciousness.
>
> <sup>More at [**Source**](http://www.thisisinsider.com/westworld-finale-twist-ford-2016-12)</sup>

Comment: Is this not somewhat complicated by the scene in which the boy host has an extended discussion with the man in black, wherein he is definitely 'channelling' Ford? the voice modulation leaves no doubt.